# how to make async request to sync request using javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
 function abc() {
    console.log(0)
    console.log(1)
 setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(2)
    },0)
    console.log(3)
}
abc()
```

I know this is async request how can i make it to sync. Can anyone help me on this please output should be 0,1,2,3

Comment: remove the setTimeout part ?

Comment: Removing `setTimeout` would give the result you want. (0, 1, 2, 3)

Comment: Why i remove setTimeout don't want to use it

Comment: The short answer is to use `async` / `await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript there are three ways to handle asynchronous calls, `callbacks` *(deprecated)*, `Promises` *(only when you must)* and `async/await` *(recommanded)*.

Using `async/await`

```js
function asyncFunction() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(2);

      resolve();
    }, 0);
  });
}

async function  abc() {
  console.log(0);
  console.log(1);

  await asyncFunction();
  console.log(3);
}

abc();
```

Using `Promises`

```js
function asyncFunction() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(2);

      resolve();
    }, 0);
  });
}

function abc() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log(0);
    console.log(1);

    asyncFunction()
      .then(() => {
        console.log(3);

        resolve();
      });
  });
}

abc();
```

There are tons of tutorials online explaining what theses are and how to use properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
async function abc() {
  console.log(0)
  console.log(1)
  await setTimeout(() => {
    return Promise.resolve(1);

  }, 0)
  console.log(3)
}
abc().then(console.log(2))
```